# Can't configure CultureInfo for Blazor Hybrid on Windows platform

Tags: blazor, cultureinfo, webview2, blazor-hybrid

Blazor Hybrid for Windows platform keeps `en-us` for the culture. Therefore date pickers and numeric inputs can't be properly configured. Problem seems related to WebView2 which dev teams claims to have documentation about this but I fail to understand how one is supposed make the configuration.

I tried configured the App default culture and other trick on start-up but nothing changes, I keep having `MM/dd/yyyy` format for date and dot for decimal separator when I expect `dd/MM/yyyy` date format and a coma as separator.

Comment: Have you read through this discussion topic which sounds similar on GitHub? https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1956

Comment: Well I tried their solution but it didn't work - I added a comment to ask if I missed something.
And thanks for the edited question, that's neet